# How to restart docker service using python SDK

Tags: python, docker

Well am trying to automate certain docker action using python and in a scenario, I need to restart the docker service if its mount loading is not properly done. How can implement the below command using python SDK?

```
  service docker restart
```

For implementing the same I tried with a [reference link](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/services.html).

But it seems not working. Any hints or suggestion is well appreciated

Comment: That's not an option in the Docker SDK.  ("Restart the server" isn't typically an option most APIs provide.)

Comment: Restarting a system service is not done via the Docker API or any Docker SDK.